# change the background color of Intellij IDEA tips pane

Tags: java, intellij-idea, themes, background-color, pane

the background color is deep blue ，sometimes I can not get code prompt clearly,so I want to change its color.

[image]

Comment: `code prompt clearly` what code? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58686890/change-the-background-color-of-intellij-idea-tips-pane) your question to include this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so to fix this problem

1.Click on "File" in the upper hand corner.

2.Click on "Settings"

3.Appearance should pop up in the settings window.

4.Click on "theme" (should be the first option you can change in the Appearance section).

5.Change it to your preferred theme (this will change your entire IDE color, however) and the tips color should change as well.

Hope this helps!